# Jquery mobile, how do I manually change the page on the "pagebeforeload" event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to redirect a page using the method defined in the docs

```
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeload", function( event, data ){

// Let the framework know we're going to handle the load.

event.preventDefault();

// ... load the document then insert it into the DOM ...
// at some point, either in this callback, or through
// some other async means, call resolve, passing in
// the following args, plus a jQuery collection object
// containing the DOM element for the page.

data.deferred.resolve( data.absUrl, data.options, page );

});
```

But I'm not sure what params exactly resolve is taking I can't find the docs anywhere, what exactly is the page param there?

Comment: You should redirect on pagebeforechange

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, what I ended up doing was creating a hidden button, then triggering a click event on that button. I know this is probably not the correct way to do it, but I thought I'd offer up a solution/hack. If anyone else has something better I would really like to hear about it.

JS

```
$("#login-btn").click();
```

HTML

```
<div style='display:none;'><a href="#login" id='login-btn' data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" >HIDDEN</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are referring to the `page` object loosely [referred to here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html).

So I think you would want something like this:

```
var page = $("#page2");
```

That may answer your question, but probably won't do much to solve your problem. There are several ways to handle this, but here is an example of how to redirect to a specific page on `pagechange`: http://jsfiddle.net/BD9ax/

Hope this helps resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the following args, plus a jQuery collection object
// containing the DOM element for the page.
```

They are using `page` to denote that extra argument. e.g.

```
var $page = $('<div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true">'
    + 'your content'
    + '</div>');
data.options.pageContainer.append($page);
data.deferred.resolve(data.absUrl, data.options, $page);
```

This is with jQuery Mobile 1.3.